# HeidiSql - keep getting error 1064

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting the error which appears in the following picture when I try to make a new table:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE SalesKicker {
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
BedrijfsName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
ContPers VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
TelNum INT(20),
Plaats VARCHAR(30),
Land VARCHAR(30),
PostCode VARCHAR(30),
GebrDat TIMESTAMP
}
```

Can somebody tell me what I`m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parenthesis, not curly braces. Also, do not forget the semi-colon at the end of your statement and put your key declarations at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE SalesKicker (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  BedrijfsName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  ContPers VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  TelNum INT(20),
  Plaats VARCHAR(30),
  Land VARCHAR(30),
  PostCode VARCHAR(30),
  GebrDat TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: Ah many thanks! thought you had to use curly braces. A little mistake of mine. Thank you!